# Does Aurelia have ng-template alternative?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, production, aurelia

I am curious is that possible to compile Aurelia js application to one minified.js file. With templates to avoid extra requests at production?

Similar to `ng-template` https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-ng-templates in angular

Comment: Take a look at Aurelia Bundling http://blog.durandal.io/2015/09/11/bundling-aurelia-apps/  https://github.com/aurelia/bundler

Comment: https://github.com/aurelia/skeleton-navigation Look at "Bundling" section

Comment: Wow, awesome. Seems it what I looking for. Thanks @FabioLuz

Comment: Are we able to make self-contained bundles with aurelia bundler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aurelia apps can be bundled.  There's a couple ways to do this:

1. Use the [aurelia bundler](http://aurelia.io/docs.html#/aurelia/framework/1.0.0-beta.1.0.7/doc/article/bundling-your-app-for-deploy)
2. Use [jspm bundle directly](http://patrickwalters.net/my-best-practices-for-aurelia-bundling-and-minification/)

Comment: This seems like a popular and accepted answer.  I would caution you, however, that it could still be flagged as a link only answer, since the context of the answer depends on the information provided by those links, which makes the answer useless if the links change.  You may want to provide some relevant information from each site in the answer body.